# wxpython error, Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

When I try to run wxpython on my company's Linux server, this error occurs.  I just cannot figure out why.

```
>>> import wx
>>> app = wx.App()
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
```

only TWO lines are entered, and this error message shows up every time when I try to run "app = wx.App()".  Anybody have any idea why?  Thanks.

Comment: I find a similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge     .  But the problem is that I am using linux server of my company, and I don't have any permission to install anything, so the answer for that post does not work for my case.

Comment: I have worked it out.  The reason why this error shows up is because I run a scripts on Linux; however, that scripts is supposed to be operated under windows.  When I run it again on windows, everything is fine.  Hope this can be helpful for people who encounter the same problem.  Good luck.