# My wxpython app looks different in conda (linux)

Tags: gtk, wxpython, miniconda

I'm sure it's straightforward, but I cannot get it.

My wxpython app was used to looks like this with the system python interpreter:[image]
But from miniconda it looks like this: [image]

Can somebody explain me which packages I'm missing?

The only clue I have are this missing modules:
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

Comment: Take a look at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20518346/16775594) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55133676/16775594). The second one has the solution in the comment. You could also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69604839/16775594), if the second one didn't help.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin thank you but no luck. I'm in conda, so no libcanberra-gtk module. I'm not even sure if this is an issue or a feature... it can be that in Ubuntu if finds some libraries not available in the conda environment.